# How to get color in terminal but no color in output file

Tags: io-redirection, colors, tee, pty, interactive

To show output in both terminal and to a file, `tee` can be used like below

```
ls --color=auto | tee opfile
```

But now, there is no color in the terminal. If I force colors, opfile also has colors which affects greping and other tools that parse the opfile.

```
ls --color=always | tee opfile # Now opfile has colors
```

Is there a way to to have colors in terminal but not in output file? Showing `ls` for example. Assume it is some command that compiles and spits out errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove colors from the file:

```
sed -e "s/\x1B[^m]*m//g" opfile
```